# Dropbox "Unable to make a secure connection"

Tags: networking, internet-connection, dropbox

Installing Dropbox on my new hard drive (Windows 10, a Samsung 860 EVO if that matters.)

When I try to run Dropbox, I get a pop-up message saying "Unable to make a secure connection to the Dropbox servers because your computer's date and time settings are incorrect." I'm doing this on my home network through an ethernet connection.

In accordance with that pop-up, Dropbox's help site, and answers.microsoft.com, I've tried:

- Checking the system time. It's set automatically, and it certainly
  looks correct.
- Going to the LAN settings and unchecking the three
  boxes. (This has something to do with proxies.)
- Going to the Windows Defender Firewall, checking "Dropbox" for
  private networks (it's already checked for public.)
- Turning off the firewall.
- In the Dropbox preferences, unchecking "Enable LAN Sync"
- In the Dropbox preferences, selecting "No Proxies" instead of "Auto-detect"

Interestingly enough, Windows Defender Firewall shows my home network and my cell-phone hotspot as "Guest or Public Networks", not private ones.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by disabling my anti-malware software and reinstalling Dropbox. It remains to be seen if it will connect after a reboot.